# Apply if else to a live log WSO2 carbon log

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm grepping a live log and need to compare the response time. If the response time is greater than 5000, "Response time greater then 5000" needs to be printed on screen preferable with the response time.

Current script :

`tail -f  request-response-logger.log| grep getSubscriberTypeResponse | awk -F 'RESPONSE_TIME:' '{print $2}'| awk -F ',BODY:<soapenv:Body' '{print $1}'`

Output:

```
255.0
289.0
352.0
236.0
365.0
520.0
472.0
528.0
560.0
522.0
557.0
586.0
493.0
```

I tried below code snippet. But it didn't work

```
if [$(grep getSubscriberTypeResponse | awk -F 'RESPONSE_TIME:' '{print $2}'| awk -F ',BODY:<soapenv:Body' '{print $1}') -gt 100]; then echo  "greater than 100"; fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below command

```
tail -f  request-response-logger.log | awk -F'[,:]' '{ if($13 > 5000.0 ) { print } }'| grep 'TRANSACTION:response' | grep getSubscriberTypeResponse
```